# Scroll broken in pageid-controlled microsite - only in desktop Safari

Tags: css, safari, scroll, overflow

*UPDATE:
I rebuilt the page with all relatively-positioned elements and the thing is still stuck when I navigate via pageid. I think it's definitely a Safari-specific overlap conflict and it is super annoying. Any ideas out there?*

I'm working on a microsite that uses pageid's to navigate through full-page div's, arranged vertically with the overflow hidden. It works just fine on every browser, including mobile, except desktop versions of Safari.

The div's scroll when the page is refreshed to the specific pageid, and will scroll if the text is highlighted and dragged, but if you start at page 01 and navigate to page 02 (like you're supposed to), the content will not scroll.

It seems like it might be an overflow conflict, but I tried to do this with the page div's scrolling horizontally to separate the x- and y-axis issue and I got nothing. It's acting more like there's a transparent layer in between me and the scroll...

Check out the microsite here: http://www.kevinjbeaty.com/trailtool-stackoverflow
Note that it works just fine everywhere else.

This is the basic html:

```
<div class = "viewbox">

<div id= "page01" class="page">
<div class="content">
**these are photos that do not scroll**
</div>
</div>

<div id= "page02" class="page">
<div class="content">
**these are photos that do not scroll**
</div>
<div class="contentscroll">
**this is text that should scroll**
</div>

<div id= "page03" class="page">
<div class="content">
**these are photos that do not scroll**
</div>
</div>

<div id= "page04" class="page">
<div class="content">
**these are photos that do not scroll**
</div>
<div class="contentscroll">
**this is text that should scroll**
</div>

</div>
```

and the basic css:

```
.viewbox {
position: relative;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
display: block;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: black;
z-index:0;
}

.page {
position: relative;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
display: block;
z-index:1;
overflow: scroll;
background-color: white;
z-index:10;
}

.content {
position: absolute;
padding: 2%;
background-size: contain;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
display: block;
}

.contentscroll {
position: absolute;
padding: 2%;
overflow-y: scroll;
overflow-x: hidden;
display: block;
z-index: 200;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it! Wow.

I changed the body "overflow" to "hidden" and got rid of the ".viewbox" wrapper altogether and viola! Stupid simple...